# Accessing local variables in dataframe select query Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I need to access local variables of Python, and use it inside dataframe.
**My Code is:

```
 var1 = "abc";
 var2 = "001";
 DF = DF_prev.select("x","y",var1,var2);
```

**

I would like to use the varibles inside select() of dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: This won't work since select() expects columns as parameter. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve this by using lit().
ie., if I use .withColumn("alias_name",lit(var1)).select('var1'), it is working fine.